# LibGDX: How to relibably determine if the opengl context got lost?

Tags: android, libgdx, opengl-es-2.0

Is there a callback to get notified after the openGL context got lost?

I've tried ApplicationListener/Game.resume() but (on Android) there are some cases where resume() gets called although the context was not lost. As well as some other cases where the context did get lost, but resume() was not called at all.

What is the right way to reliably determine if the openGL context got lost in libGDX?

Answer (score 0):

There's no straightforward [solution](http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=1073) for an app with both managed and unmanaged/dynamic textures. The article explains why you cannot really get a trigger. I would recommend to use [AssetManager](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Asset-manager) so you can ***update*** your assets on ApplicationListener's ***resume*** method. You should visit and read both links.

Answer (score 0):

It is highly unlikely that you will ever have a context loss in the first place. See [this post](http://badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=20757&p=86095#p86095) for a more detailed explanation. But even if you do have a context loss (which would only happen on very old Android devices running Android 2.x), then libGDX will take care of that for you and restore the resources for you. You don't have to do anything for that.

It is more likely that you somehow "think" that you are having a context loss, while in reality you have another problem. For example, the most common reason for people to think that they have a context loss, is when they are using `static` resources. E.g. by using the singleton pattern with lazy initialization.

Ofcourse, without seeing any code, this is just guessing.